# Is a pyspark dataframe cached the first time it is loaded

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that i load via a spark sql query from a hive datastore. I understand that the query only executes when I call an operation like show() on the dataframe.

If I call an operation on the dataframe multiple times,will the query be reexecuted, or is it possible to cache it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call an action, all transformations are (re)executed based on its lineage.  Therefore if you want to improve performance, you have to call `persist() or cache()`.  After a call to persist, the subsequent actions doesn't have to redo its entire lineage, rather its starting point would be from persisted RDD

Comment: Thank you. So before calling persist, i need to call an 'Action',correct? If I just say:df=hive_context.sql("SOME_SQL"); df.persist(), it will not work because I did not call an action?

Comment: Also, which pyspark package i need to import to use this function persist()